# Dynamic saving of files .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this function that save the file in the `wwwroot` foldar:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
   if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
       return Content("file not selected");

   var path = Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", file.FileName);

   using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
   {
      await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Files");
}
```

I'm trying to save the files dynamically so that every time a file is uploaded the function will check whether there is a folder with the user ID (from the session). If the folder exists, it is saved there, otherwise, it will open a new folder with his ID.

I want to create a sub folder for each userId and save user specific file to that folder

Comment: You're like 98% there. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I don't know what i need to change to make it happend....

Comment: At this point, you should probably take a day and read a starter's programming book. Also, check into tutorials about how to debug and examine variables at runtime, such as `path` (what needs to be added to change it to the value you need), Directory.Exists (checking for existence) and HttpContext.Current (how to get the user ID).

Comment: @EfratCohen Would you like to create a sub folder for each userId and save user specific file to that folder?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1):

I added this and now it'ts working

```
var userId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");

        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(
                    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"wwwroot/{userId}")))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(
                    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"wwwroot/{userId}"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the current user's id is:

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Then, you just work this into your path:

```
var path = Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"wwwroot/users/{userId}", file.FileName);
```

Comment: but what can I do if the Directory is not existed?

Comment: Create it? `if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) Directory.Create(dir);`. Obviously, you'll need to affix the filename portion to the path afterwards, or you can use `Path.GetDirectoryName(path)` for the directory check/create portion.